# Tableau: How to get moving average with respect to day of week in last 4 weeks?

Tags: moving-average, tableau-api

e.g: If I have the data as below:

```
Week 1      Week2       Week3
S M T W T F S   S M T W T F S   S M T W T F S 
2 5 6 7 5 5 3   4 5 7 2 4 3 2   4 5 2 1 2 7 8
```

If today is Monday, my average will be (5+5+5)/3 which is 5. Tomorrow it will be (6+7+2)/3 which will be 5 again and day after it will be (7+2+1)/3 which will be 3.33

How to get this in Tableau?

Comment: Research partitioning and addressing in table calculations, starting with the online help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use "Weekday" as a column or row (by rightclicking on the date).

Then you can simply add a Table Calculation "Moving Average" with a specific computing dimension "Week of [Date]"

=> [Table Calculation Specifics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esRfD.jpg) <=

=> [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5lA7.jpg) <=

Comment: If you have "empty" days, like I do, you might also want to go to "Analysis" -> "Table Layout" -> "Show Empty Columns", to see every wekday in every week. In that case date-filters won't have the effect on the plot, that you might want, so you have to filter the dates on the data-level.

Comment: Simple and superb! Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Data source used-: Tableau Sample Superstore.

You can do the following-:
Columns-: Week(Order Date)
Rows-: Weekday(Order date)

Put Sales in text.
Right click sales>Quick Table Calculation>Moving Average

right click Sales>edit quick table calculation> 
Set the following
Select Moving along-: "Table across"
Previous values-: 4